# JupyterLabのダークモード化をコマンドで行いたい

Tags: python, docker, wsl, jupyter-lab

Win10のWSL2上で、Dockerを用いてJupyterLabを使いたいと考えています。
このとき、コンテナを起動するごとにマウス操作で毎回ダークモードにするのは避けたいと考えています。

そのため、Jupyter notebookをダークモードにするのと同様に

`jt -t onedork -fs 95 -altp -tfs 11 -nfs 115 -cellw 88% -T`
してから
`jupyter lab`
として起動しましたがダークモードになりませんでした。
マウスを用いてダークモード化することはできました。

コマンドでダークモードにすることは可能なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**

[黒背景でvimキーバインドなJupyterLabを起動するDockerイメージ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/leo-mon/items/f388279424cddfc24357)

上記ページを参考に、[Kaggle Python (Dockerイメージ) の Dockerfile](https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python/blob/master/gpu.Dockerfile) 内にコマンドを追記しましたが、うまく行かなかった（内容は下記の補足参照）ので
マウントするフォルダ内の.jupyterフォルダにhemes.jupyterlab-settingsファイルを作り、{"theme":"JupyterLab Dark"}と記述しましたが、起動時にダークモードになりませんでした。
設定が反映されていないようですが、どうすれば反映されるでしょうか。

**再追記**

Dockerfileからechoで{"theme":"JupyterLab Dark"}を書くパターンも試しましたが、やはりこちらも変わりませんでした。
`/tmp/working/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/themes.jupyterlab-settings`
というフォルダ構成です。

**補足**
上記のリンクをそのままDockerfile内に貼り付けると、以下のようになりうまく行っていないようです。
mkdirは特に何も出ていないのでうまく行っていると見てよいのでしょうか。
themes.jupyterlab-settingsはechoする前に空のファイルを作らなければならないということでしょうか？

```
Step 40/42 : RUN mkdir -p /home/jovyan/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension
 ---> Running in 24cc635c44ee
Removing intermediate container 24cc635c44ee
 ---> ba8a1b1e09a3
Step 41/42 : RUN echo '{"theme":"JupyterLab Dark"}' >   /home/jovyan/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/themes.jupyterlab-settings
 ---> Running in 099d05db7ca3
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/jovyan/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/themes.jupyterlab-settings: Directory nonexistent
The command '/bin/sh -c echo '{"theme":"JupyterLab Dark"}' >   /home/jovyan/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension/themes.jupyterlab-settings' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

**再補足**
rootユーザーにして`./build --gpu`してみましたが、
やはりmkdirのところで-pオプションをつけないとエラー、つけるとエラーは出ませんがディレクトリが生成されないというのは変わらないようです。
`# 深い意味はなく他ユーザーを作成するが省略可能`、のところ

```
USER root

RUN groupadd student && useradd -m -g student student
RUN mkdir /home/student/notebooks
RUN chown -R student:student /home  # プラグインインストールには/home/jovyan以下への権限が必要
```

もDockerfileに記述しましたが変わらずという感じです。

Comment: これらの記事の背景(テーマ)を設定する部分が参考になるのでは？ [黒背景でvimキーバインドなJupyterLabを起動するDockerイメージ](https://qiita.com/leo-mon/items/f388279424cddfc24357), [おじさん、DockerでPythonの勉強環境を作る](https://qiita.com/mottai/items/9fb922933c1e1c327f6e)

Comment: ありがとうございます。.jupyter/...のディレクトリにthemes.jupyterlab-settingsを置き、{"theme":"JupyterLab Dark"}と記述しましたが、起動時にダークモードになりませんでした。どうにも読み込まれていないように思われます。どのように対応すればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 行ったことやその結果、および何か関連してそうな情報の詳細を、省略無しで質問に追記してください。現象や対策を知っている人が居れば、助言や回答が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: 追記された内容だと、何か省略して書いていないのか、理解が不足してその手順になっているのか区別が付かないでしょう。紹介した記事に書かれているように、設定ファイル/起動用スクリプト等の内容や(Windows側かDocker側かも含めて)それらのある場所とか、実行する際にどの場所でどういう入力を行ったか、といった詳細を記述してみてください。`マウントするフォルダ内の.jupyterフォルダ`とか`/tmp/working/.jupyter...(以後省略)`だと、実際には何処であるか曖昧だし、紹介先記事と対比するとイマイチ正しくない感じがします。

Comment: ユーザーを切り替えていない/そのつもりでも切り替わっていないとか、作ったディレクトリのパーミッション設定が違うとかでは？ エラーの最初が`/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/...`なので、Exit Codeは 1:Operation not permitted だと思われます。[Linux bash exit status and how to set exit status in bash](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bash-exit-status-set-exit-statusin-bash/)

Comment: JupyterLabを起動するDockerイメージ、のページで不要と言われた`USER root`から`mkdir /home/student/notebooks`も記述しましたが、`mkdir`で`No such file or directory`になってしまいました。-pをつけたらエラーも出なくなりましたが、おそらく`mkdir`は成功していない気がします。また、`echo`のところで`Directory nonexistent`になるのも同じです。おっしゃるとおり権限周りが怪しい気がします。

Comment: rootになってdockerをビルドし直してみようかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Docker イメージに載せるところまでは詳しくわからないので部分回答になります。

---

[JupyterLab のドキュメント](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/extension_dev.html?highlight=dark#extension-settings) を見ると、ダークモードを有効にしたい場合は以下の内容を `overrides.json` というファイルに記述し、`<sys-prefix>/share/jupyter/lab/settings/` ディレクトリの下に置けばよいとあります。

```js
{
  "@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes": {
    "theme": "JupyterLab Dark"
  }
}
```

なお、`<sys-prefix>` についてはコマンドで `jupyter lab path` を実行すれば確認できるようです。

**参考:**
[JupyterLab User Settings File - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58843537) の回答